# Spring Boot Application with MySQL database issue

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

Please help new at spring framework, i have issue running app i bealive its  MySQL database which located in localhost .if any one can see problems

https://github.com/EKholif/confranceApp.git

[image: 1]

```
2023-02-20T21:08:18.450-05:00 ERROR 6684 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ReflectionManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1130) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:905) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringAppli
```

Comment: In you git repo, I see there is no configuration for JPA (such as datasource url, jpa,...) in file `application.properties`. Spring Boot has autoconfiguration which will auto create JPA Beans based on configuration in properties file.

Answer (score 0):

I got your Point and I have cloned your code and configured and successfully able to run your application.

The exception you are getting "Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'" because you have not defined the speaker model as entity and if once you will define it as @entity annotation you have add primary key also.

I have corrected your code and pushed it on my git hub for your reference [corrected_code_url](https://github.com/amisham96/stack_overflow_answer)

attaching screenshots that I am successfully able to run and craeted tables also in mysql database.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: i did and still have same issue.

Comment: please if u could check it on git hub it may have more issues

Comment: Please check again I have have modified the answers and corrected your code as well. its working fine